# (gcloud.kms.encrypt) Failed to read plaintext file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-kms

I want to encrypt a key file with the `gcloud` command line tool.

The command I am running is:

```
gcloud kms encrypt --project=pname --location=global --keyring=keyring \
--key=key-credential \
--plaintext-file=/Users/macuser/Desktop/test/keys/testkey.json.decrypted \
--ciphertext-file=testkey.json.encrypted
```

but I keep getting the error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.kms.encrypt) Failed to read plaintext file 
[/Users/macuser/Desktop/test/keys/testkey.json.decrypted]: 
Unable to read file [/Users/macuser/Desktop/test/keys/testkey.json.decrypted]: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/Users/macuser/Desktop/test/keys/testkey.json.decrypted'
```

The file

> /Users/macuser/Desktop/test/keys/testkey.json.decrypted

exists. I tried it with absolute and relative path, and with and without quotes, but I keep getting the same error.

Why is gcloud not seeing the file?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure the user that is calling the encrypt and decrypt methods has the `cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt` and `cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToDecrypt` permissions on the key used to encrypt or decrypt.

One way to permit a user to encrypt or decrypt is to add the user to the `roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypter`, `roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyDecrypter`, or `roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter` IAM roles for that key.

2. To use Cloud KMS on the command line, first Install or upgrade to the latest version of Cloud SDK.

```
gcloud kms encrypt \
    --key key \
    --keyring key-ring \
    --location location  \
    --plaintext-file file-with-data-to-encrypt \
    --ciphertext-file file-to-store-encrypted-data
```

- Replace key with the name of the key to use for encryption.
- Replace key-ring with the name of the key ring where the key is located.
- Replace location with the Cloud KMS location the key ring.
- Replace `file-with-data-to-encrypt` and `file-to-store-encrypted-data` with the local file paths for reading the plaintext data and saving the encrypted output.